# How to control argument passing policy in pybind11 wrapping of std::function?

Tags: pybind11

I have a class in c++ that I'm wrapping into python with pybind11. That class has a std::function, and I'd like to control how the arguments to that function are dealt with (like return value policies). I just can't find the syntax or examples to do this...

```
class N {
public:
   using CallbackType = std::function<void(const OtherClass*)>;
   N(CallbackType callback): callback(callback) { }
   CallbackType callback;

   void doit() {
      OtherClass * o = new OtherClass();
      callback(o);
   }
}
```

wrapped with

```
py::class_<OtherClass>(...standard stuff...);

py::class_<N>(m, "N")
   .def(py::init<N::CallbackType>(),
      py::arg("callback"));
```

I all works: I can do this in python:

```
def callback(o):
   dosomethingwith(o)

k = N(callback)
```

, but I'd like to be able to control what happens when `callback(o);` is called - whether python then will take ownership of the wrapped `o` variable or not, basically.

---

I put a printout in the destructor of OtherClass, and as far as I can tell, it never gets called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think I figured it out:

Instead of std::function, use a pybind11::function:

`using CallbackType = pybind11::function`

and then

```
void doit(const OtherClass &input) {
        if (<I want to copy it>) {
            callback(pybind11::cast(input, pybind11::return_value_policy::copy));
        } else {
            callback(pybind11::cast(input, pybind11::return_value_policy::reference));     
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing in `pybind11/functional` that allows you to change the ownership of the parameters at the point of call, as the `struct func_wrapper` used is function local, so can not be specialized. You could provide another wrapper yourself, but in the code you can't know whether the callback is a Python function or a bound C++ function (well, technically you can if that bound C++ function is bound by pybind11, but you can't know in general). If the function is C++, then changing Python ownership in the wrapper would be the wrong thing to do, as the temporary proxy may destroy the object even as its payload is stored by the C++ callback.

Do you have control over the implementation of `class N`? The reason is that by using `std::shared_ptr` all your ownership problems will automagically evaporate, regardless of whether the callback function is C++ or Python and whether it stores the argument or not. Would work like so, expanding on your example above:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/functional.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

class OtherClass {};

class N {
public:
   using CallbackType = std::function<void(const std::shared_ptr<OtherClass>&)>;
   N(CallbackType callback): callback(callback) { }
   CallbackType callback;

   void doit() {
      auto o = std::make_shared<OtherClass>();
      callback(o);
   }
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    py::class_<OtherClass, std::shared_ptr<OtherClass>>(m, "OtherClass");

    py::class_<N>(m, "N")
       .def(py::init<N::CallbackType>(), py::arg("callback"))
       .def("doit", &N::doit);
}
```